# ReferenceError $timeout is not defined angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here i add a delay in javascript forloop using $timeout. Unexpectedly i got an error saying 
 
*ReferenceError $timeout is not defined*. i am new to angularjs please help me.
[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZklGCiBzkb9mDAiyY6rF?p=preview)

```
function CompLibrary() {
  return {
    init: init
  }
  function init(dependencies, controller) {
    dependencies.push(controller);
    angularApp.controller('MainCtrl', dependencies);
  }
}
var compX = CompLibrary();
compX.init(deps, _controller);
function _controller() {
  var ViewModel = this;
  ViewModel.search = "Name";
  ViewModel.quantity = 1;

  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    (function(i){ 
        $timeout(function() {
            ViewModel.quantity++;
        }, i * 2000);
    })(i); // Pass in i here
  }

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var deps = [];
var angularApp = angular.module('plunker',[]);
function CompLibrary() {
  return {
    init: init
  }
  function init(dependencies, controller) {
    dependencies.push('$timeout');
    dependencies.push(controller);
    angularApp.controller('MainCtrl', dependencies);
  }
}
var compX = CompLibrary();
compX.init(deps, _controller);
function _controller($timeout) {
  var ViewModel = this;
  ViewModel.search = "Name";
  ViewModel.quantity = 1;

  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    (function(i){ 
        $timeout(function() {
            ViewModel.quantity++;
        }, i * 2000);
    })(i); // Pass in i here
  }

}
```

By injecting `$timeout` in the controller function we can solve this problem.

Answer (score 9):

You have to `inject` the `$timeout` into the controller function.

```
function _controller($timeout) { ... }
```

Please see updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/j2Vt4AhUYNkPXeKQ7Il3)